# Cassandra: Geospatial support

Tags: cassandra

What would be the best way to implement geospatial queries on top of Cassandra?

By geospatial I mean be able to query for data objects based on their geographic location.
For example, find the 10 restaurants nearest to a user's current location.

I thought of one possible solution, but it seems to be a terrible hack:
Make rows serve as "buckets" of ranges of both latitude and longitude data (separately).
Then save locations as columns into appropriate rows, by ascending order.
Query for 20ish closets restaurants by their lat, long (separately, again), then intersect the 2 sets.

I'm starting to think this might be a serious pitfall of the Cassandra model.

Answer (score 0):

The basic b-tree indexes are there in cassandra in the form of wide rows.  PlayOrm has a complete SQL language on cassandra though with partitions so you are not joining billions of rows with billions of rows and instead join partitions.  I imagine doing geospatial would be similar to what PlayOrm has but I am guessing.  I mean is geospatial doable with b-tree's and such?  If so, it just means you have to do a bit of heavy lifting.  I know at one point, PlayOrm was considering adding some geospatial features but we never got around to it.....we would always accept work in that area though.

later,
Dean